# Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 LTS - Samba failure of Windows access to Ubuntu shares

Tags: networking, upgrade, samba

I upgraded to 18.04 from 17.10. I thought that I was doing a good thing, but discovered that the working samba in 17.10 now fails on 18.04. Tried many things and read many possible solutions. But so far I have yet to resolve the issue.

Unless I find a true fix, I must settle with re-installing 17.10 to restore samba share access from Windows. 
Is there any real fix for this issue?
This latest version was supposed to fix the performance issue with samba. But alas, it has broken it entirely.

Any ideas to fix this please?

windows Version pre & post Ubuntu Upgrade= Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.48]

Contents of `smb.conf`

```
[global]
    workgroup = pedhome
    server string = Samba Server %v
    netbios name = ubuntu1710
    security = share
    map to guest = bad user
    name resolve order = bcast host
    dns proxy = no
    bind interfaces only = yes
    usershare owner only = false
    encrypt passwords = no
    guest ok = yes

[Volume1]
    path = /media/Volume1
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes

[Pictures]
    path = /home/robert/Pictures
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
```

Comment: Please post the relevant entries from `smb.conf`, and also please indicate Windows version.

Comment: Windows Version used to access Ubuntu17.10 successfully= 10.0.17134.34

Comment: I'm having a similar problem when doing a trial upgrade of my server in a virtual machine.  It was working fine in 16.04, does not work in 18.04 with the same smb.conf.  I get the dreaded error 13 when trying to connect.  This is from a Linux client, so it's not just windows.  What changed in samba? It is difficult to find out.

Answer (score 0):

After two days I finally got Win10 to see Ubuntu 18.04 samba shares. (Still a newbie)

On the 18.04 box:

Load samba using Linuxconfig.org instructions. version 4.7.6.
I restarted it repeatedly during the process to verify continued operation. (samba restart)

Samba V1 was deprecated/removed from Win10 by Microsoft (even Netgear got caught with that one)

Verify WORKGROUP matches the rest of the network in smb.conf file.

Add user with smbpasswd -a newusername

Right click on filefolder you want to share from Nautilus. Share folder and give read/write to users.

On the Win10 box:

Go to explorer. In the quick access bar enter \\linuxmachinename. Hit Enter and you should see the Linux shares. Double click one and a user/password window should come up. Enter the smbpasswd user/password you entered on the Linux box. You may still need to change read/write and ownership on the Linux box.

Re-boot both machines, whisper special incantations, and poof, you'll probably have frog legs for dinner.